# How can I split the string in php?

Tags: php

I have a string like $str.

```
$str = "00016cam 321254300022cam 321254312315300020cam 32125433153";
```

I want to split it in array like this. The numbers before 'cam' is the string length.

```
$splitArray = ["00016cam 3212543", "00022cam 3212543123153", "00020cam 32125433153"]
```

I have tried following code:

```
    $lengtharray = array(); 
    while ($str != null) 
    { 
         $sublength = substr($str, $star, $end); 
         $star += (int)$sublength; // echo $star."<br>"; // echo $sublength."<br>"; 
         if($star == $total)
         { 
             exit; 
         }
         else
         { 

         } 

          array_push($lengtharray, $star); // echo 
          print_r($lengtharray); 
    }
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I have try this. $lengtharray = array();

while ($str != null) {
    $sublength = substr($str, $star, $end);
    
    $star += (int)$sublength;
    // echo $star."<br>";
    // echo $sublength."<br>";
    
    if($star == $total){
             
        exit;
    }else{
        
    }
    array_push($lengtharray, $star);
    // echo print_r($lengtharray);

}
But don't work well.

Comment: you can use explode function to create a array from $str

Comment: Sorry, My string is like this. $str = "00016cam 321254300022cam 321254312315300020cam 32125433153" It is not include **. I don't know how to get the regular to explode. Only try the substr().

Comment: Will it always contain three 0 on every start or will it change?

Comment: The three 0 will change. Because the number before 'cam' is the split string's length. The range is 00000 to 99999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string doesn't contain stars then I'm afraid you need to write a simple parser that will:

- take characters from the left until it's not numeric
- do `substr` having the length
- repeat previous steps on not consumed string

  ```
  <?php

  $input = "00016cam 321254300022cam 321254312315300020cam 32125433153";

  function parseArray(string $input)
  {
      $result = [];

      while ($parsed = parseItem($input)) {
          $input = $parsed['rest'];
          $result[] = $parsed['item'];
      }

      return $result;
  }

  function parseItem(string $input)
  {
      $sLen = strlen($input);
      $len = '';
      $pos = 0;
      while ($pos < $sLen && is_numeric($input[$pos])) {
          $len .= $input[$pos];
          $pos++;
      }

      if ((int) $len == 0) {
          return null;
      }

      return [
          'rest' => substr($input, $len),
          'item' => substr($input, 0, $len)
      ];
  }

  var_dump(parseArray($input));
  ```

Comment: I have tried to understand your function step by step. It is the awesome answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this 1 line solution

```
$str = explode('**', preg_replace('/\**cam/', 'cam', $str)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me. hope helps.

```
$str = "**00016**cam 3212543**00022**cam 3212543123153**00020**cam 32125433153";
$arr = explode("**", $str);
for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($arr); $i=$i+2) 
    $arr_final[]=$arr[$i].$arr[$i+1];
```